# What is the best way to detect function key being pressed?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, air

How can I most reliably detect a function key being pressed using an windows application that sits waiting for it in the background?

Ideally I would like an application that can be run on Windows, Linux and Mac's so I'm wondering if maybe it can be done using Adobe air.

I want the function key to be detected regardless of what application the user is currently using.

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates what you need to do.

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid477E4BD57EA637D92D19A65FEF3E160B4C7C139F.aspx

In short, it starts with a call to the Win32 API function SetWindowsHookEx.